R: How to calculate power to detect a change in mean beta reg.?
I'm interested in calculating the power to detect a change in my mean response variable by a certain effect size, but I'm not sure how to start. My Y variable is mean plant cover 0-100% cover (mean of 10 random replicate surveys per site, as a decimal, including 0 and 1), and I'd like to calculate the power to detect an effect size for a future hypothetical change in cover (one/paired-sample test). Plant cover is repeatedly sampled every year at the same locations (random intercept).
I typed this question into chatgpt, but I'd like to verify this is the correct method. It responded with suggesting I make two separate models (one in which my covariate has no effect, and another where it has a specified effect), then calculate the difference between the two mean responses from each model. It then says to calculate power using a t-test.
Does this answer seem correct? How would I accurately simulate data that looks like my raw data (how do I choose alpha and beta in rbeta)? How would I make my year covariate have a specific effect on cover (chatgpt assumed a continuous covariate and set it to 0.5)? Also, I know my response isn't a probability, but shouldn't I use a power calculation for a proportion as this is 0->1 data (i.e., use pwr::pwr.p.test)?
I tried simulating the data to make it easier to post this question, but it didn't have the intended effect in the summary output.
set.seed(123)

n <- 100
x1 <- rep(seq(1, 10), each = 10)
x2 <- seq(1, 10)

y <- rbeta(n, 2, 5)  # Simulate response variable (beta distributed)

# Create data frame
data <- data.frame(cover = y, year = x1, site = x2)
data$site <- as.factor(data$site)

I thought this would be better than betareg as it allows for random intercepts
library(glmmTMB)
# Fit beta regression model
model <- glmmTMB(y ~ year + (1|site), ziformula = ~1, data = data, family=beta_family(link="logit"))

Chatgpt:
# Simulate Data for Power Calculation:
# To calculate power, you typically need to simulate data under the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis.

# Null Hypothesis (H0): Assume the predictor variable x1 has no effect.
# Alternative Hypothesis (H1): Assume the predictor variable x1 has an effect of a certain size.
# Let's assume you want to calculate power for detecting a difference in the mean response variable y between two values of x1: x1 = 0 and x1 = 0.5.

# Simulate data under H0 (no effect of x1)
data_null <- data.frame(y = rbeta(n, 2, 5), x1 = rnorm(n))

# Simulate data under H1 (effect of x1 = 0.5)
data_alt <- data.frame(y = rbeta(n, 2, 5), x1 = rnorm(n, mean = 0.5))



model_null <- betareg(y ~ x1, data = data_null)
model_alt <- betareg(y ~ x1, data = data_alt)

# Calculate difference in mean response variable (y) between x1 = 0.5 and x1 = 0 under H0
mean_y_alt <- predict(model_alt, newdata = data_null)
mean_y_null <- predict(model_null, newdata = data_null)
effect_size <- mean(mean_y_alt - mean_y_null)

# Standard deviation of y
sd_y <- sd(predict(model, type = "response"))

# Sample size
n <- nrow(data)

# Significance level
alpha <- 0.05

# Calculate power
power <- pwr.t.test(n = n, delta = effect_size, sd = sd_y, sig.level = alpha, type = "two.sample")$power
power

This is a better test for proportion data, no?
power <- pwr.p.test(h = effect_size, n = n, sig.level = alpha, alternative = "two.sided")$power
power


If you have 10 years (as in your example), are you interested in treating year as a continuous covariate (i.e. testing for linear [on the log-odds scale] trends over time), or in estimating whether there is an overall significant difference among years (treating years as either a categorical fixed effect or as a random-effects grouping variable, i.e. year-as-cluster)? (I can't say I'm super-enthusiastic about cleaning up after ChatGPT, although I appreciate that you made the effort ...)

The general idea of simulating data with a specific effect size and seeing how often you can reject the null hypothesis is a good idea, though. The combination of simulate_new() + glmmTMB() + a for-loop (or replicate or map or whatever) should do it ... the t-test and 'power of a proportion test' stuff seem to be red herrings.

@BenBolker, sorry, I wasn't keen on using ChatGPT, but had to start somewhere. I wasn't sure what might be easier (detecting a change in slope between year 1 and 10, or comparing means of two groups/factors of 5 years worth of data; i.e. a sort of "before" and "after" comparison). Either works more me. Thank you for looking it over.

I started to write an answer but realized I was making it very complicated. I think you should figure out first what kind of test you want to run (year 1 vs year 10? average of year 1-5 vs year 6-10? slope of trend from year 1 to year 10?) and what kind of random effects you think are reasonable/would put in the model. Then it will be relatively easy to show you how to generate simulations/fit models/test effects/summarize effects to compute the power for a specified set of assumptions. But I think "how should I test this?" is a separate question from "how do I calc power of this test?"

The answers to your questions about "how do I decide what parameters to use?" are that you have to (1) understand what the parameters mean and (2) play around with options until you get results that look like they would be realistic for your context.

@BenBolker, thank you for your last comment (+1)! I thought I had to estimate alpha and beta via some regression or something. Apologies for the disjointed question. To clarify, would calculating the power to detect a change in the mean response between two levels of time as a factor (5 years prior vs. 5 years before) be considered a retrospective power analysis (is that "allowed")? If that's ok to do, I'd like to know how to set that up, please. Site should be a random effect. I'd like to calc. the power using several effect sizes, as well (if not too much trouble). (1/2)

I think that ChatGPT has misled you somewhat (not surprisingly).

I tried simulating the data to make it easier to post this question, but it didn't have the intended effect in the summary output.

That is a great idea. I am very much a fan of doing power calculations via simulation. It is not always easy, but by doing it that way you can control whatever you want to control. In other words it is very flexible. So, the main problem with your simulation lies here:
y <- rbeta(n, 2, 5)  # Simulate response variable (beta distributed)

Here you have simulated y but it does not depend on year or site. In order for this to work we need to incorporate these dependencies. Luckily it is not too hard to do, so I have adapted your code. It computes the power to detect an effect size of 0.08 for year. Hopefully it is self-explanatory, but if not, feel free to ask (or point out any deficiencies).
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(15)
n_sites <- 10                   # Number of sites 
n_years <- 5                    # Number of years
n_rep <- 5                      # Number of replicate surveys per site per year

n <- n_sites * n_years * n_rep  # Total number of observations

year <- rep(rep(1:n_years, each = n_rep), n_sites) 
site <- rep(1:n_sites, each = n_years * n_rep)     

n_sim <- 50                   # Number of simulations
vec_pvalues <- numeric(n_sim) # Vector to store the p-values
eff_size <- 0.08

for (i in 1:n_sim) {
  
  # Simulate random intercepts for `site`
  random_effects <- rnorm(n_sites, 0, 0.5)  
  
  # Linear predictor (year effect and random effect for site)
  eta <- eff_size * year + random_effects[site]
  
  # Inverse logit transformation to bound the mean between 0 and 1
  mu <- plogis(eta)
 
  # Precision parameter for the beta distribution
  phi <- 10  

  # Simulate beta-distributed response variable y
  y <- rbeta(n, mu * phi, (1 - mu) * phi)
  
  data <- data.frame(cover = y, year = year, site = site)
  data$site <- as.factor(data$site)
  
  # Fit beta regression model
  model <- glmmTMB(cover ~ year + (1|site), ziformula = ~1, data = data, family=beta_family(link="logit"))
  
  # Extract p-value for the effect of `year`
  vec_pvalues[i] <- coef(summary(model))$cond[2, 4] 
}
# Calculate power
mean(na.omit(vec_pvalues) < 0.05)

That results in 0.82 in this instance.
Ideally there should be some code to check for convergence issues. In this instance there were none, so I didn't bother with that.

This is great, thank you! Just a couple of follow-up questions, if I may. How might I adjust the effect size if I want to have the power to see a certain % change in cover (30% change, for example)? I know how to relate a percent change to cohen's h using ES.h(p1, p2), but didn't understand how a percent change relates to a regression parameter effect size (Beta). Also, how might phi change as well? How do I choose that value?

Great questions! I’m just on my way out now but will try to get back to you later on today. If I don’t then it’s likely I forgot about it so if I don’t respond by tomorrow, give me a kick in these comments :)

You got it, thanks again

FWIW the simulate_new() function from glmmTMB can simplify the simulation process ... need to specify newdata (the covariate values/experimental design structure), newparams, family ...

@Nate did you mean to tag Ben, or me ? I've been thinking about your questions. For the % change, I think you can just do $\beta = \text{logit}(p_2) - \text{logit}(p_1))$ where $p_1$ is the baseline proportion of cover and $p_2 = p_1 \times (1 + \text{%change})$. However I am not too confident that it's correct so you might want to post a new question about that. For choosing phi, you can start with a reasonable value (eg phi = 10) and adjust based on the expected variability in the cover data. A higher phi leads to less spread, and a lower phi leads to more variability.
